# Fail to change the legend title and label with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, legend

I was trying to change the legend title from group to the Greek letter "sigma" and the label "power.1, power.2, power.3" to "35, 40, 45" but it did not appear and still shows the default name and label. Could you please help me with it? Thanks so much.

```
# Load the library and input the data
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

n <- 2:10
control <- rep(150, 4)
infected <- c(150, 170, 200, 250)
all <- c(control, infected)
sigma <- c(35, 40, 45)

# Compute the population mean
mu <- mean(all)
# Compute the sum of the tau squared
tau2 <- sum((all-mu)^2)
# Compute the gamma
gamma.1 <- (n*tau2)/(sigma[1]^2) 
gamma.2 <- (n*tau2)/(sigma[2]^2) 
gamma.3 <- (n*tau2)/(sigma[3]^2) 
# Compute the power
power.1 <- 1-pf(qf(.95, 7, 16), 7, 16, gamma.1)
power.2 <- 1-pf(qf(.95, 7, 16), 7, 16, gamma.2)
power.3 <- 1-pf(qf(.95, 7, 16), 7, 16, gamma.3)

data <- data.frame(n, power.1, power.2, power.3)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("power"), names_to = "group", values_to = "power") %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, power)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = group), size = 4) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = expression(sigma), labels = c("35","40","45"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the final part of your code. One lesson you can learn is that fill and color are different aesthetics. So, if you set color you must use `scale_color_manual`. Here the code:

```
#Code
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("power"), names_to = "group", values_to = "power") %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, power)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = group), size = 4) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = expression(sigma), labels = c("35","40","45"))
```

Output:

[image]

Or you can also try with `guides()` which will produce the same output (But first option is more direct):

```
#Code 2
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("power"), names_to = "group", values_to = "power") %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, power)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = group), size = 4) +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("35","40","45"))+
  guides(color=guide_legend(title=expression(sigma)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and the second code. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should used:

```
scale_colour_discrete(name = expression(sigma), labels = c("35","40","45"))
```